# Why is my assembly code not jumping to the loaded code?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I wrote a simple OS / bootloader that loads 4 additional sectors from disk and then jumps to them. But the jump isn't working and the code just hangs.
This is the start.S file

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

PROGRAM_SPACE equ 0x7E00

start:
    mov bp, 0x7c00
    mov sp, bp

    call ReadDisk
    mov bx, DiskSuccesString
    call print
    jmp 0x7E00


hang:
    jmp hang

print:
    push ax
    push bx

    mov ah,0x0e
    .loop:
    cmp word [bx], 0
    je .exit
        mov al,[bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp .loop
    .exit:
    pop ax
    pop bx
    ret





ReadDisk:
    mov ah, 0x01
    mov bx, 0x7E00
    mov al,4
    mov dl,[BOOT_DISK]
    mov ch,0x00
    mov dh,0x00
    mov cl,0x02
    int 0x13

    jc DiskError
    ret

BOOT_DISK:
    db 0

DiskError:
    mov bx, DiskErrorString
    call print
    jmp $

DiskErrorString:
    db 'Error while reading Disk     ',0

DiskSuccesString:
    db 'Succes!',0


times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; pad to 512 bytes and add MBR bootable signature
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

This is the kernel.S file:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7E00]
mov ax, 0x0000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0xFFFF

mov bx, msg
call print


jmp $

print:
    push ax
    push bx

    mov ah,0x0e
    .loop:
    cmp word [bx], 0
    je .exit
        mov al,[bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp .loop
    .exit:
    pop ax
    pop bx
    ret

msg:
    db 'Welcome to PotatOS',0

times 2048-($-$$) db 0
```

And this is the file I use to assemble everything:

```
#!/bin/zsh
rm start
rm kernel
nasm start.S
nasm kernel.S
cat start kernel > os.bin
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -hda os.bin
```

I used a label for the address but replaced it with the actual address but nothing changed.

Comment: May be related or not, but definitely needs to be fixed: initialize the segment registers to 0 **before** doing `ReadDisk` or any memory access.

Comment: And setting the stack pointer to an odd address is weird.  If you want the stack at the very top of segment 0 you can simply set `sp = 0`; the first push will decrement it to `0xfffe`.

Answer (score 3):

### Lots of loose ends here

The only bit of information that your bootloader program receives from BIOS is the disk identification in the DL register. You can't trust the segment registers to contain suitable values. You have to setup these yourself so they suit whatever it is that you aim to do and especially have them accord with the `ORG 0x7C00` setting:

```
xor  ax, ax
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
```

> ```
> mov bp, 0x7c00
> mov sp, bp
> ```

Always change the SP stackpointer register in tandem with the SS segment register. And always modify the SS register directly before the SP register:

```
xor  ax, ax
mov  ss, ax       \ Always together and in this order
mov  sp, 0x7C00   /
```

> ```
> ReadDisk:
>   mov dl,[BOOT_DISK]
> ```

Your *ReadDisk* routine retrieves a value from the *BOOT_DISK* variable, **but that variable never got initialized**. Use `mov [BOOT_DISK], dl` as soon as you have setup the segment registers (at least DS).

> ```
> ReadDisk:
>   mov ah, 0x01
> ```

**You are not loading anything**. 0x01 is a function that returns the disk status in the AH register. The BIOS function that can read sectors from a disk has number 0x02.

> ```
> jmp  0x7E00
> mov  bx, 0x7E00
> ```

Seeing that line `PROGRAM_SPACE equ 0x7E00`, it would make sense to write it like: `jmp PROGRAM_SPACE` and `mov bx, PROGRAM_SPACE`.

> ```
> print:
>   push ax
>   push bx
>   ...
>   pop ax
>   pop bx
>   ret
> ```

What you put on the stack needs to come off in reverse order!

```
push ax        \
push bx   \    |
...       |    |
pop  bx   /    |
pop  ax        /
```

> ```
> cmp word [bx], 0
> ```

Your messages are ASCIIZ strings. They are suffixed by a single zero-**byte**. Don't try to detect this terminator with a word-sized operation. And because the BIOS.Teletype function also uses BX for some of its inputs, you should refrain from using BX as your message pointer. Use one of the other address registers. eg. `cmp byte [si], 0`.

### Rewrite of start.S

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

PROGRAM_SPACE equ 0x7E00

start:
    xor  ax, ax
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  es, ax
    mov  ss, ax
    mov  sp, 0x7C00
    mov  [BOOT_DISK], dl     ; Initialize with info from BIOS

    call ReadDisk
    mov  si, DiskSuccesString
    call print
    jmp  PROGRAM_SPACE

print:
    push ax
    push bx
    mov  bx, 0x0007    ; DisplayPage 0, GraphicsColor 7
    mov  ah, 0x0E
.loop:
    mov  al, [si]
    inc  si
    int  0x10
    cmp  byte [si], 0
    jne  .loop
    pop  bx
    pop  ax
    ret

ReadDisk:
    mov  dh, 0
    mov  dl, [BOOT_DISK]
    mov  cx, 0x0002
    mov  bx, PROGRAM_SPACE   ; ES:BX is buffer
    mov  ax, 0x0204
    int  0x13
    jc   DiskError
    ret

DiskError:
    mov  si, DiskErrorString
    call print
    jmp  $

BOOT_DISK:
    db 0

DiskErrorString:
    db 'Error while reading Disk', 0

DiskSuccesString:
    db 'Succes!', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Don't forget to rewrite kernel.S based on the above.

> ```
> mov ax, 0x0000
> mov ss, ax
> mov sp, 0xFFFF
> ```

Anyway it is not a good idea to change the SS:SP again. And definitely always choose an even number to put in the SP register. 0xFFFF is a real bad choice!

Comment: thanks alot for the help! i'm fairly new to intel asm and now i can finaly start working on the real kernel. Thanks to everyone whom replied